# Dual Monitors not working (One black)

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Currently running Windows 7 Profession 64 bit with i5, think I would be able to write better code if I add a 2nd monitor so I grab an old one and hook it up to the 24(+1) DVI port using a DVI to VGA adapter. Unfortunately, it's black, and nothing shows up. They work fine apart, but once put together: Nothing.

The display shows up in the monitor control panel, but the option to change resolution does nothing. Monitor stats below.

13x13 Square ViewSonic VA 705b with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 625 (OEM)

Comment: After you connect the 2nd one, have you tried enabling it by using `Windows Key+P`?

Comment: What happens if you try to move a window (eg, open notepad) out of the screen (As if you were moving it to the other screen)? Does it try to dock on the edge, or does it allow the move?

Comment: Does any single monitor work using VGA adapter?

Comment: Have you checked you have the latest drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: I have enabled the dual screen system with Win + P, still not working, although the resolution on my main screen changed. If I triy to move the window to the left side of the screen, it does not dock, and instead goes past the screen.  Neither monitors work singlely if I connect using the DVI-VGA adapter. The drivers are up to date.

Comment: try hooking the second monitor with the same hardware at your friend's house and see if it works if not buy a new one

Answer (score 3):

1. Maybe it sounds stupid, but do you have both monitors connected to the video card, and one not to the motherboard? (It's easier to overlook this than you'd think).
2. Does the monitor have more input options, if so, it might just be on the wrong channel. Use the source button, or a menu button to cycle through channels until you are on the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> fixed it. I guess that the second monitor just had to be nudged after being asleep.